# How to avoid looping the album/playlist automatic?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, google-play-music

I use the default "Play Music" music player app (v4.3.605.398337) for listening to music. Whenever it gets to the end of an album/playlist it automatically replays it.

I would like to avoid that behaviour but I can't find where/how to: does anybody know?

<sup>If relevant, my device is Galaxy Nexus.</sup>

Comment: Try updating the app to the latest version 4.3.615.48117.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You could try clicking the bottom right "repeat" icon, i.e, if you haven't tried that already.

Comment: OMG, I feel so stupid. Thanx varunyellina, I had not see that button